# Woocommerce. Valoraciones con estrellitas pero sin comentarios

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-plugin

Estoy intentando que en Woocommerce me deje poner las estrellas sin necesidad de escribir un comentario pero parece obligatorio hacerlo. Alguna idea? Gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Agrega en el archivo functions.php

```
add_filter('allow_empty_comment', '__return_true');
```